# How to replace elements of one array with rows of another array in Numpy

Tags: numpy

I have two arrays of variable length and content (simplified example):

```
A = np.array([[0.25, 0.25], [0.25, 0.75], [0.75, 0.25], [0.75, 0.75], [0.8, 0.9] ...]) 
B = np.array([0, 1, 2, 4, 0, 3, 3, ...])
```

What is the best/fastest way to get an array where every element of B is replaced with the corresponding row from A (B as index) so that the result would be:

```
C = [[0.25, 0.25], [0.25, 0.75], [0.75, 0.25], [0.8, 0.9], [0.25, 0.25], [0.75, 0.75], [0.75, 0.75], ...]
```

I am somehow at a loss (still a beginner with problems getting my head around numpy).

**Edit/addendum**: Forgot to mention: I would like to avoid loops since the arrays are big and time is critical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use [direct indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays):

```
C = A[B, :]
```

Results in

```
[[ 0.25  0.25]
 [ 0.25  0.75]
 [ 0.75  0.25]
 [ 0.8   0.9 ]
 [ 0.25  0.25]
 [ 0.75  0.75]
 [ 0.75  0.75]]
```

[IDEOne Link](https://ideone.com/AtUGQ9)

Comment: Thx, exactly what i was looking for. Hope i will some day get a better grasp of Numpy. :)

Comment: @kukuschi. Keep using it and you will. It's inevitable.